# Error when trying to add extra data to a resource response

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I'm trying to add some extra data to a specific resource, so I followed the documentation regarding [Decorating a Serializer and Add Extra Data](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization#decorating-a-serializer-and-add-extra-data) but when I tested the resource I got this error:

> Call to a member function normalize() on null in (...)/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php, line 426.

I been struggling with this error for almost two days and I don't know if I am missing some detail or this isn't the right way to add extra data to a resource. 
This is my resource definition:

```
AppBundle\Entity\MediaGenerator\Teaser:
   attributes:
   access_control: "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
     normalization_context:
       groups: ['teaser','teaser-read']
     denormalization_context:
       groups: ['teaser','teaser-write']
     order:
       position: 'ASC'
```

Here is my custom normalizer:

```
class ApiNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $normalizer)
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof Teaser;
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $data['view'] = "SOME TRANSFORMATION ON TEASER VIEW";
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->normalizer->supportsNormalization($data, $type, $format);
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->normalizer->denormalise($data, $class, $format, $context);
    }
}
```

And here is my services.yml declaration:

```
AppBundle\Serializer\ApiNormalizer:
      decorates: 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item'
      arguments: [ '@AppBundle\Serializer\ApiNormalizer.inner' ]
      autoconfigure: false
```

Everything else works as a charm, the serializer in config.yml is enabled as `{ enable_annotations: true }`.

Any toughts?

Thanks in advance and great work with ApiPlatform!

Answer (score 1):

## First things first, check that the serializer is enabled

https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    serializer:
        name_converter: 'serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case'
```

#### The bane of injected dependecies

What you're running into here, is a missing injected dependency. Mostly because the method you're calling doesn't run the same dependency check of code everywhere else. Specifically:

```
// $this->serializer is NULL
return $this->serializer->normalize($attributeValue, $format, $context);
```

You'll notice in [`Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php::normalize`](https://github.com/symfony/serializer/blob/master/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php):

```
if (!$this->serializer instanceof NormalizerInterface) {
    throw new LogicException(sprintf('Cannot normalize attribute "%s" because the injected serializer is not a normalizer', $attribute));
}
```

`AbstractItemNormalizer::getAttributeValue` doesn't have this check (and *really* should.

## Normalizers need to call `setSerializer`

A quick check for the base serializer shows it to be defined as a [SerilaizerAwareTrait](https://github.com/symfony/serializer/blob/master/SerializerAwareTrait.php):

This means that every Serializer is intended to be dependency-injected into every normalizer using it, through a pattern akin to dependency-inversion (where the object itself calls a parent setter to set itself:

```
class Serializer {

public function __construct($normalizer) {
    $normalizer->setSerializer($this);
}
```

What this all boils down to is a couple requirements:

1. A Serializer MUST be instantiated with the normalizer[s] injected.
2. Your normalizer needs to be in that injections list.

This can all be seen more clearly in the [Symfony Serializer Contstructor](https://github.com/symfony/serializer/blob/master/Serializer.php)

## Where to go next?

Take a careful look at [Symfony's Sierlizer Component Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html). By Making a small adjustment to their FIRST example, you should be able to initialize everything in a way which your ApiNormalizer::serilizer is properly assigned.

```
$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new ApiNormalizer());

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
```